# C# ComboBox removing and adding

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Im trying to populate 5 different comboboxes with the same datasource. The datasource is from a class list with values like this (the values that arent displaymember im using to populate text-boxes adjacent to the combobox):

```
StandardList.Add(new Standard() { ID = 1, number = 91632, credits = 4, 
uniEntrance = "Y", assessmentType = "Ext", standardType = "AS" });
```

This is how I have populated each combobox:

```
cboNumber1.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
 cboNumber1.ValueMember = "ID";
 cboNumber1.DisplayMember = "number";
 cboNumber1.DataSource = StandardList;
 cboNumber1.Refresh();
```

When I select an item from one particular combobox, I want to remove that same item from the remaining comboboxes, and then re add it to each combobox if that item is deselcted in the focussed combobox. I have not figured out how to 're add' yet, however the 'removing' part works for every item except when I try to select the LAST item in the combobox using

```
StandardList.RemoveAt(cboNumber1. SelectedIndex);
```

it comes up with "ArgumentOutOfRangeException". My question is how do I get around this? Also if I select a particular item in the focussed combobox, and it removes that same item from each remaining combobox, how would I re-add that particular item back, at the same position, to each combobox if I deselected that particular item in the focussed combobox?

This is my first post so sorry for any bad practice. Also please bear in mind im still a highschool student so my c# knowledge is not very broad and my coding practices may be inefficient/bad. I would appreciate any answers/solutions in simple terms even if it means inefficiencies. Thanks.

Comment: can you do `StandardList.Remove(cboNumber2.SelectedItem);`?

Comment: The error you are getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is because the `cboNumber2.SelectedIndex` value is greater than the number of items in `StandardList`. 

Updating the `StandardList` will affect all of the comboboxes. You only want to remove it from the other comboboxes. Maybe look at different ways to add and remove items from a combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Selection change of the 1st combo box try to set the filtered DataSource of other combo boxes by using "Where" of list class.

like: 
StandardList.Where(item => item.ID != cboNumber1.SelectedItem.Value);

This will return a filtered list, assign this list to other combo boxes.

This will work for you. I guess..

Comment: Sorry for the delayed confirmation of solution but it didnt work at first so i had to figure a few things out. Thanks very much